# Understanding 4Rx4 on memory label

Tags: memory

I read about the meaning of 4Rx4 on memory label

4R -> quad rank -> data width of memory module is 64 * 4 = 256 bits

x4 -> data width of on DRAM chip on memory module

-> 256 / 4 = 64 DRAM chips

But on product image, I see 16 DRAM chips

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&sku=a7916527

I don't know why. Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply put, Ranks address sets of chips, so if you have 64bit ranks, and 16bit chips, then you would have 4 chips per rank yielding a total of 16 chips. My guess is that when Dell says "Chip Organization", they mean "chips per rank" rather than refering to the width of the chips on the rank. while Rank width might be notated as "X4", Chip width would not be. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_geometry  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_rank

Comment: Follow your answer, there are two meanings in "x4" on memory label: Chips per rank or data with per chips. I see the explain about memory rank in some articles: https://crucial.i.lithium.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/dram@tkb/article-id/71 and https://serverfault.com/questions/273931/difference-between-2rx4-vs-2rx8-ram

Answer (score -1):

You see 16 total because what you see is 4 sets of 4. It stacks 4 chips per package.